# How can I set a hotkey in atom (using their keymap perhaps) to print a string?

Tags: latex, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I am coding and there is a long string that i cant be asked to type out every time i need to. How could I set a shortcut?

```
example_coding.bla(bla.bla) *starts typing long string*
```

Then it recognises the start of my long string so gives me the option to press tab and auto insert the rest of it?

This is using LaTeX in Atom, but would be great if it could be for any coding language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're asking for how to create a command, but it sounds like what you really *want* is a [snippet](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/). Since you haven't provided any information about your use case, I can't tell you what to put in your `snippets.cson`, but the Flight Manual has all the necessary information.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem. :)